# How to find my pool address on uniswap?

Tags: uniswap, uniswapv3, goerli

I created a token on the Goerli Testnet and then made a pool of it with ETH on Uniswap.
How can I find my pool contract address?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you call the function "createPool()" from Uniswap v3?

If you look at this function,

```
    function createPool(
        address tokenA,
        address tokenB,
        uint24 fee
    ) external override noDelegateCall returns (address pool) {
```

it returns the address of the newly created pool. So look at the return value of the transaction where you called 'createPool()'. You can find the return value on a block explorer like etherscan. Hope this helps

Comment: I found this function in the documentation but I don't know where to use this code.
I created the token using remix.ethereum where not much code was needed. So where do I have to use this code?
@OlivierD

Comment: Then you need to find the addresses of the uniswap V3 contracts on Goerli, and create the pool by calling the createPool function with your 2 tokens addresses.

Or you can go on uniswap v3 app, click on the "Pool" tab, then on the 'more' drop down and click on "create a pool".

Those links will help you: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XtwE6tpUVX0&ab_channel=JamesBachini
and https://docs.uniswap.org/protocol/reference/deployments
Don't forget to give an upvote if my answer helped so it can help others. Thanks

Comment: I did go to v3 app and created a pool and added liquidity. But I don't know how to get its contract address.
After asking James (whose video you linked) I think I got the pool contract address from etherscan but now If I search it on info.uniswap it doesn't show up. Is it because the pool is on Goerli Testnet or am I doing something wrong? @OlivierD

Comment: answer marked accepted but can't upvote because don't have enough reputation. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

```
import "@uniswap/v3-core/contracts/interfaces/IUniswapV3Factory.sol";

uint24 fee=3000 // define fee here

//https://etherscan.io/address/0x1f98431c8ad98523631ae4a59f267346ea31f984#:~:text=Uniswap%20V3%3A%20Factory%20%7C%20Address%200x1f98431c8ad98523631ae4a59f267346ea31f984%20%7C%20Etherscan
address factoryAddress=0x1F98431c8aD98523631AE4a59f267346ea31F984

address yourPoolAddress=IUniswapV3Factory(factoryAddress).getPool(firstTokenAddress, 
                                                    secondTokenAddress,
                                                    fee)
```

[uniswap deployment addresses](https://docs.uniswap.org/protocol/reference/deployments)

- from front end, we need to create `UniswapV3Factory` and call the  `getPool` function. to create the contract we need address of contract,provider and abi of the contract:

  ```
  const { abi: UniswapV3Factory } = require('@uniswap/v3-core/artifacts/contracts/UniswapV3Factory.sol/UniswapV3Factory.json')

  const address0 = getAddressFirstTokenContract
  const address1 = getAddressSecondTokenContract
  // this is same as above I placed
  const factoryAddress = '0x1F98431c8aD98523631AE4a59f267346ea31F984'



  const factoryContract = new ethers.Contract(
        factoryAddress,
        UniswapV3Factory,
        // define your provider
        provider
  )
  ```

call the contract function:

```
// contract functions are async
   const yourPoolAddress = await factoryContract.getPool(address0, address1, 300)
```